# What does load_digits() from sklearn do?

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

Well, I've seen some questions regarding load_digits(), but all of them are regarding some feature or some comparison against other function. What I really need to know is what does load_digits do? In layman's terms. Please do not just copy the definition given in the sklearn website, I've read and I have no clue what that means.

This is the code given in the class that I didn't understand:

```
    dataset = load_digits()
    X, y = dataset.data, dataset.target

    for class_name, class_count in zip(dataset.target_names, np.bincount(dataset.target)):
        print(class_name,class_count)
```

Comment: The [API reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html#sklearn.datasets.load_digits) has a link to the User Guide, which explains in greater detail that the function is related to "[dataset loading utilities](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#digits-dataset)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In layman's terms, it loads the [MNIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) dataset, as a dictionary.

There are 5 elements in the dict:

```
Out[27]: dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'target_names', 'images', 'DESCR'])
```

Probably you've seen these before:

[image]

That's the MNIST dataset of hand-written digits. It's being used as a benchmark classification task for machine learning [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database#Classifiers), and in AI research.